# Emberjs findRecord then not waiting for resolve

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data, ember-model

I have a findRecord method with the json api convention that looks like this:

```
this.store.findRecord('book', 2).then((book) =>{
    console.log(book.get('name'));
});
```

The console log is always printing `undefined`, but the name value is actually beeing send. `book` only returns the `id` and nothing more. I tested with Ember.$ ajax and I got everything. The model structure is also correct.

Is this the normal behavior? This is driving me mad for hours...
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Working snippet:

```
Ember.$.getJSON('http://api.xxxxx.com/v1/books/' + id).then((book) => {
    console.log(book.get('name'));
});
```

**EDIT2:**

Book model:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    year: attr('number'),
    authors: hasMany('author')
});
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet i.e. Ember.$.ajax with which you got everything?

Comment: Yes @skbly7, check the edited question

Comment: Can you post the code in your Book model? Typically it would be in `models/book.js`.

Comment: Done @MaxWallace, check the EDIT2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If **{ reload: true }** is passed or adapter.shouldReloadRecord evaluates to true, then the returned promise resolves once the adapter returns data, regardless if the requested record is already in the store:

```
this.store.findRecord('book', 2, {reload: true}).then((book) =>{
    console.log(book.get('name'));
});
```

Refer: https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.Store/methods/findRecord?anchor=findRecord

Comment: Well... it worked. What does the reload equals true do?

Comment: this will force to wait until promise to get data from backend. if that reload is not specified then it will get it from store and in the background it will initiate server request and update the store.

Comment: So that means I have these books I'm calling individually already in the store? If so, could they be loaded to the store if I perform a findRecord of their parent relation first? Like, I do a findRecord for author that loads with all its books, and then a findRecord for the specific book

Comment: if that particular record is in the store then you will get it instantly,and in the background it will request server and if there is any changes then it will update the store. this is default behavior. to answer your question by the time you findRecord for specific book  if the background update is not yet finished updating all the books in store then you wont get the result.

Comment: @rafaelmsantos I welcome you to update answer with exact text if my explanation is not conveyed meaning correctly..